# Выдает ошибку на странице браузера 404 Not Found

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-template

```
    #views
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    from .serializers import UserSerializer
    from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer
    from rest_framework.views import APIView


    class UserDetails(APIView):
        renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
        template_name = 'home1.html'
    
        def get(self, request, pk):
            profile = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
            serializer = User(profile)
            return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'profile': profile})
    
        def post(self, request, pk):
            profile = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
            serializer = UserSerializer(profile, data=request.data)
            if not serializer.is_valid():
                return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'profile': profile})
            serializer.save()
            return redirect('')
        введите сюда код
    
    #url
    urlpatterns = [
        path('<pk>/', views.UserDetails.as_view()),
        path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    ]

#settings
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],


#template
{% load rest_framework %}

<html><body>

<h1>Profile - {{ profile.name }}</h1>

<form action="{% url '' pk=profile.pk %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

</body></html>
```